# Is it possible to associate an existing NIC with guest without bridge?

Tags: virsh

I have an existing virtual Ethernet device `veth0` and I want to use this for virtual-machine. At the moment, I create a bridge for this, e.g:

```
virt-install --name vm --network bridge=br0,model=e1000 ...
```

..which means that I end up with a following network topology:

```
vm[eth0] <-> [tap1]br0[veth0] ...
```

Is it possible to define simply a following network topology with `virt-install`:

```
vm[eth0] <-> [veth0] ...
```

If this is not possible from `virt-install` command line, then can this be done with `virsh edit`?